# using fibonacci sequence to print out words

Tags: python

I am writing a program where it prints out how the frequency of a word as long as the frequency is in the fibonacci sequence (1,2,3,5,8,etc). I have figured out how to print all the words that appear once, however I am having trouble figuring out how to iterate so it prints out the words that have a higher freqeuncy.

```
import string
import itertools

def fib():
    a,b = 0, 1
    while 1:
        yield b
        a, b = b, a + b

while True:
    filename = raw_input('Enter a file name: ')
    if filename == 'exit':
        break
    try:
        file = open(filename, 'r') 
        text = file.read() 
        file.close() 
    except:
        print('file does not exist')
    else:

        for word in string.punctuation:
            text=text.replace(word, "")
        word_list = text.lower().split(None)
        word_freq = {}

        for word in word_list:
            if len(word) > 1:
                word_freq[word] = word_freq.get(word, 0) + 1

        frequencies = sorted(word_freq.items(), key=lambda item: item[1])
        a = fib()
        order = sorted(word_freq.values())
        n = 1
        a = next(a)
        for words in frequencies:
            try:
                if a == words.index(n):
                    print(words)
            except:
                print('nope')  # HELP: how would I iterate here??


print('Bye')
```

Comment: Didn't you just post this question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5668969/python-using-the-fibonacci-sequence

Comment: nope, asked one that was a little more vague, figured out some stuff, got stuck again

Comment: Just keep calling a.next() to get the next value from your fibonacci generator.

Comment: just got that part, how do I increment words.index(n).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing the end of your `while` loop to the following:

```
    f = next(a)
    for words in frequencies:
        # we need a new value from fib, since we have passed the current one
        while words[1] > f:
            f = next(a)
        # if the frequency of this word matches the fib value, print it
        if words[1] == f:
            print(words)
```

Answer (score 1):

You're overwriting the generator object when you call next.

Calling `fib()` returns a generator. To get the next value, you use `next(a)` which returns the value. Then you assign it to a, which overwrite your generator, so you can't use it anymore. Instead, do something like `value = a.next()`, and execute that each time you need to get the next value in the fib sequence.

By the way, it would probably make more sense to iterate through fibonacci numbers and look for those in the frequencies, rather than iterating through the frequencies. Otherwise, you'll have to reset your fibonacci generator every time.

You can find the max frequency in the list, and stop your fibonacci iteration once the sequence has exceeded that value.